# How starvation occurs in producer consumer problem

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

Please give an example producer consumer scenario where starvation occurs.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we can use an example for demonstrate the answer. But an example cannot be **the only purpose** of the answer. Why do not take the examples from the net? If you do not understand some *existing* example, you may ask specifically about it.

Comment: I don't find any example from google thats why I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

If correctly coded producer-consumer problem is always going to be starvation free.

- Consumer blocking till there is ready buffer to consume.
- Producer blocking till there is empty buffer to produce.
- Producer after producing immediately moving buffer to ready buffer queue.
- Consumer after consuming immediately moving buffer to empty buffer queue.

This arrangement can not lead to starvation.

But if you introduce a bug like:

- Consumer on certain condition is not returning the previously consumed buffer to empty buffer queue and continuing to wait for next ready buffer ready to be consumed.
- Or Producer on certain condition is not returning produced buffer to ready buffer queue and continuing to wait for empty buffer to produce.
- Then eventually this kind of situation will lead to starvation.

This kind of "waiting while holding buffer" scenario can lead to starvation.